# udev doesn't create symlink to device when using a custom rule

Tags: linux, arch-linux, hard-disk, udev

I have created the following `foo.rule`

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{serial}=="D93E7DF61B000174", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0x61b6", SYMLINK+="foo"
```

The respective `serial`, `idVendor` and `idProduct` is the respective values provided by `lsusb` (with modifiers). Afterwards, I triggered the rules using `udevadm trigger`. There should be the respective device file `/dev/foo`, however, no such file exists.

Comment: could you try with: `SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{serial}=="D93E7DF61B000174", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0x61b6", SYMLINK+="foo"`
also, could you add the complete `udevadm trigger` command you used? Also, did you try rebooting and simply plugging in the device?

Comment: @madeddie still not working. The command `udevadm trigger` is plain, without any modifiers.

Comment: i have no more ideas

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdf
```

to see the attributes as `udev` does; that greatly helps troubleshooting issues like this. In particular, on a random USB drive, I notice that idVendor and idProduct should *not* have the `0x` prefix. So you should try:

```
… ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="61b6", …
```

Comment: I've tried the non-octal values, no change whatsoever. However, the reboot (yes, I know...) helped, thus switching back to non-octal.

Answer (score 0):

The most trivial approach, `reboot`, helped - procedures like

```
udevadm control --reload
udevadm trigger
```

hadn't yielded the proper results. The following `.rule` works fine on `4.7.0-1-ARCH`

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{serial}=="D93E7DF61B000174", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="61b6", SYMLINK+="foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the answer was to change your rule from `ACTION="add"` to `ACTION="add|change"`.